# Python type hints: Making generic type inference work with inheritance

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting

Let's say I have some abstract `Node` class. Each Node should take some input data and produce output data, each of a potentially different type. To make development easier, to see what `Node`'s are compatible with other `Node`'s, I want to use type hints, so I have:

```
T_In = TypeVar("T_In")
T_Out = TypeVar("T_Out")


class Node(Generic[T_In, T_Out]):
    input_: T_In
    output: T_Out

    def __init__(self, input_: T_In):
        self.input_ = input_
        self.output = None

    def prepare_output(self):
        raise NotImplemented()

    def get_output(self) -> T_Out:
        return self.output
```

So far so good (this is of course not meant to be directly instantiated).

Now I have a subclass `MapNode` that takes some function that does the actual data conversion. I want to use the type signature of the function to automatically determine the types for the `Node` class. More specifically, this node always takes a list of some type (equivalent to the function's input type), and produces a list of another type (function output type). What I tried is this:

```
T_Lambda_In = TypeVar("T_Lambda_In")
T_Lambda_Out = TypeVar("T_Lambda_Out")
New_IT = TypeVar("New_IT", bound=List[T_Lambda_In])
New_OT = TypeVar("New_OT", bound=List[T_Lambda_Out])

class MapNode(Node[New_IT, New_OT]):
    def __init__(self, input_, lambda_: Callable[[T_Lambda_In], T_Lambda_Out]):
        super(Node, self).__init__(input_)
        self.lambda_ = lambda_

    def prepare_output(self):
        self.output = [self.lambda_(obj) for obj in self.input_]
```

A function could be, for instance:

```
def cast_int(val: str) -> int:
    return int(val)
```

My thinking was that this should generate the type hints:

```
node: MapNode[List[str], List[int]] = MapNode(["1", "2"], lambda_=cast_int)
```

Instead, PyCharm generates:

```
node: MapNode[Any, Any] = MapNode(["1", "2"], lambda_=cast_int)
```

It seems that the usage of the types in the function signature is not enough to resolve the "derived" types `T_Lambda_In` and `T_Lambda_Out` correctly. Any help in fixing this would be appreciated! I'm using Python 3.6 by the way.